# Ошибка при сохранении данных в файл

Tags: java, activity

Здравствуйте.

Приложение состоит из двух activity, первый - основной, второй - настройки. Настойки сохраняю в файл через `SharedPreferences`. По нажатию на button "save" вызываю функцию, которая сохраняет настройки, и потом создаю новый Intent для перехода на главный экран.

Собственно проблема:
После нажатия на button "save" настройки сохраняются и выдаёт ошибку: "Приложение ... остановлено", соглашаюсь, и он перекидывает на основной activity, в котором нормально считывает только что сохранившиеся данные... В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема а том, что нет стактрейса и кода

Comment: Эм...  Я тут всего несколько часов, ещё не успел разобраться как что куда добавлять прикреплять и тд...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Кому интересно, в чём была проблема. Немного обманул вас, на самом деле активити не 2, а 3. В первом пользователю предложено выбрать дату, после чего он переходит на второй активити и передаёт в него данные через Intent... Во втором активити в функции OnCreate с помощью getStringExtra эти переменные извлекаются. Так вот, при переходе из активити настроек мы переходили на активити 2, который пытался извлеч переменные, которых не существует, и, естественно, на это ругался... )))))